# applying Green's theorem and integrating along the curve without applying Green's theorem

Tags: calculus

Green's theorem says $\int _cP dx+ Qdy=\int\int _D \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)$

Applying this theorem in the following example $\int _c x^4dx+xydy$, where $c$ is a triangular curve consisting of line segments from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$, from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)$, from $(0,1)$ to $(0,0)$ I get the answer as $\frac{1}{6}$

I wanted to evaluate the integral along the curve without using Green's theorem and see if I get the same answer. My limits for $x$ and $y$ are $0\leq x\leq 1$ , $0\leq y\leq 1-x$

When I parameterise, I have $x=r\cos t$, $y=r\sin t$, I don't know how to find $r$ and limits of $t$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the domain:

$$
D := \left\{ (x,\,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 \le x \le 1, \; 0 \le y \le 1-x \right\},
$$

whose boundary is the curve:

$$
\partial D := \gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2 \cup \gamma_3
$$

with:

$$
\small
\gamma_1 :
\begin{cases}
x(t) = t \\
y(t) = 0
\end{cases}
\; \; \; \text{for} \; t \in [0,\,1]\,;
\; \; \;
\gamma_2 :
\begin{cases}
x(t) = t \\
y(t) = 1-t
\end{cases}
\; \; \; \text{for} \; t \in [0,\,1]\,;
\; \; \;
\gamma_3 :
\begin{cases}
x(t) = 0 \\
y(t) = t
\end{cases}
\; \; \; \text{for} \; t \in [0,\,1]\,;
$$

by **definition** of *line integral*, we have:

$$
\small
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\partial^+ D} \left(x^4\,\text{d}x + x\,y\,\text{d}y\right) 
& = 
\int_0^1 \left(t^4 \cdot 1 + t \cdot 0 \cdot 0\right)\text{d}t +
\int_1^0 \left(t^4 \cdot 1 + t \cdot (1-t) \cdot (-1)\right)\text{d}t +
\int_1^0 \left(0 \cdot 0 + 0 \cdot t \cdot 1\right)\text{d}t \\
& =
\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{30} + 0 \\
& = 
\frac{1}{6}\,,
\end{aligned}
$$

while for the *Gauss-Green* **theorem**, we have:

$$
\small
\int_{\partial^+ D} \left(x^4\,\text{d}x + x\,y\,\text{d}y\right)
= \iint_D \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x\,y\right) - \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(x^4\right)\right)\text{d}x\,\text{d}y
= \int_0^1 \text{d}x \int_0^{1-x} y\,\text{d}y
= \frac{1}{6}\,.
$$

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

In addition here are some notes for the area integration in polar coordinates.

**The limits of the integration in polar coordinates**

The $\theta$ angle comes from $0$ to $\pi /2$. The $r$ comes from $0$ to $\frac{1}{\cos \theta + \sin \theta}$.

[image]

On the picture $a = r \cos \theta$, $b = r \sin \theta$, $a + b = 1$ and finally
$$
r = \frac{1}{\cos \theta + \sin \theta}
$$

The jacobian of the transform is the $r$, so $dxdy = r dr d\theta$

### Definite integration

$P = x^4$, $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = 0$

$Q = xy$,  $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = y$

$$
  \int\int_D y \, dx dy = 
  \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} d\theta \int_{0}^{\frac{1} {cos\theta + \sin\theta}} r^2 \sin \theta \, dr =
  \frac{1}{3} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin \theta}{(\sin\theta + \cos\theta)^3} \, d \theta = \frac{1}{6},
$$

see [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29%20%2F%20%28sin%28x%29%20%2B%20cos%28x%29%29%5E3%20dx%2C%20x%3D0..pi%2F2) for the last step